# Where art thou, tags? Or a request to make tag formatting guidance easier to discover

Tags: feature-request, tags, formatting

I've been fixing tag formatting on meta for tag-related requests [for years](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/1752727/post-revisions-by-user-id-with-comment-containing-text?Comment=tag%20formatting&UserId=11407695). For those unaware, its syntax is `[tag:name]` for tags on the main site and `[meta-tag:name]` for those only present on the child meta. When rendered, the item receives special styling highlighting that it is a tag and a link to questions tagged with it.

Upon pointing out to authors of such posts that there is a special tag formatting syntax, I *always* get a response with genuine surprize that such a feature exists, both from new users and highly experienced ones alike. I've also had discussions ([example](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/54731584#54731584)) with peers with interest in tag curation where they expressed that the knowledge about the feature can't be easily obtained.

The guidance on formatting tags is tucked away under the "More" link that, as evidenced by so many users not being aware of the feature at all, pretty much nobody reads:

[image: screenshot of the formatting tips section of the post editor with the "More" link highlighted]

Ideally, we should have an interactive tutorial on posting on Meta, but given that expecting such a complex feature to be implemented is wishful thinking, let's at least increase the visibility of the guidance a little by inlining it in the formatting tips section of the editor (there definitely is enough unused space to fit one short item).

Here is an example markup of how it *could* look like:

[image: screenshot of a mockup extension to formatting tips with a "Tags" button to the right of the "Tables" button and the open section dropdown with guidance on how to format tags]

Granted, the new editor adds an action for inserting properly formatted tags:

[image: screenshot of the new editor with special formatting dropdown opened and "Tag (Ctrl-[)" button highlighted]

However, it has several issues that prevent me from considering the issue to be obsolete:

- It removes inline formatting tips *entirely*, admittedly, exacerbating the problem further.
- It tucks away tag formatting under the dropdown, which, let's be frank, most users will easily miss.
- It is still in heavy development, and one has to explicitly opt-in to use it.

Comment: This has traditionally, like `<kbd>`, been one of those features intentionally kept from being overly promoted to new users. Not only is it a nice trick to learn as you get familiar with the site, but more importantly, the slightly-elevated barrier to entry keeps down abuse. Think of the way people abuse inline code formatting everywhere. Now, do you want to see them start doing this with tag formatting? I didn't think so.

Comment: @CodyGray well, evidently, users abuse any formatting they are given (bold, emphasis, strikeout, links, images, tables, code, you name it), so I don't think I see any problem with making it more discoverable for the few that are capable of following guidance. Besides, the new editor that SE is likely to impose on us at some point makes all of the options even easier to abuse.

Comment: As if I needed more reasons to hate the new editor. I thought "fundamentally broken" and "garbles the text I typed" were sufficient. Anyway, when I see that users abuse any formatting that is made easily accessible to them, I start thinking of ways to make that formatting less accessible and enticing. You want to… make it *more* discoverable? I don't see how that helps. The folks who are capable of following reasonable guidance don't seem to have any trouble discovering this. A short time of reading posts by experienced users on Meta easily reveals the "trick", which is very easy to remember.

Comment: Kind of like that, @CodyGray, since I do not believe security-by-obscurity (and making formatting help [an important note is that I'd like the tips to be more visible, not the option itself, as opposed to what the new editor does] obscured by a single link is a kind of one) is helping much, especially given that over the whole period that I've been heavily involved in tag curation, I am yet to see a single post abusing tag formatting - on the contrary, I keep seeing code formatting abused to highlight tags as users don't know better. I would also like to clarify that the request concerns [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] Meta only, I don't see any point in adding it for extending formatting tips on main either. All that said the request is more of a form of documentation, as we both know that chances SE actually doing anything for the public platform at this point (apart from pushing the "AI" angle) are basically non-existent...

Comment: ([An example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73776861/populating-a-v-data-table-with-filtered-data-from-firebase) with all italics... Though [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/71567701/1) takes the biscuit.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen I was under the impression that you're our great editor. How come you haven't done your duty yet?

Comment: @Andreas detests censorship: I might. It is part of a notes entry titled *"Samples of overformatted Stack Overflow posts"*

Answer (score -5):

Go to stackoverflow.com home page and you see "Top Questions" and a list of questions, but no indication whatsoever about what the site is about or how one should use it. The same is true for all the other .SE sites:

[image]

You're asking for far too little.

Everything here is like a game where one has either to discover new knowledge (e.g. that tag formatting exists) or to earn knowledge that in a normal world would be available to everyone (e.g. up/down votes).

Unless you can change the whole system, there's not much point in worrying about small details.

Comment: That is the "logged in" view though, when you're not logged in you get a very different view. Still, I agree that the UI is designed for human beings to make every mistake possible. Zero guidance unless you go look for it in obscure pull down menus with oddly positioned links.

Comment: "*Unless you can change the whole system, there's not much point in worrying about small details.*" – Uh, no? Small improvements are absolutely worthwhile. That attitude is extremely defeatist, and doesn't lead to a win for anyone at all; if we don't pursue the small wins, why should the big ones be any different? The fact that the system needs all the improvements it does is _more_ credence that we should be improving every piece we can, not less.

Comment: We could opt in for putting blinking big arrows all over the page, for every user with less than 20 reputation.

Comment: @zcoop98. Generally (not specific to SE), allowing small victories after long battles is how those in power dissipate opposition. As long as the much larger underlying situation remains, what amount to token efforts are like being able to bail with a larger bucket when you're on the Titanic. There's a definite policy here of making things difficult for beginners and slightly less difficult for the experienced. Learning how to properly format tag labels is a good thing, but it won't change the overall situation.

Comment: *"…you see "Top Questions" and a list of questions, but no indication whatsoever about what the site is about or how one should use it…"* Err, based on the information presented as you describe, I would conclude that the site is probably a place where questions are asked and answered, and that you should use it by asking questions and getting answers. (There's also a search box, which suggests another way to use it: search for existing answers.) And that's pretty much accurate. So I'm not really sure that you've chosen the best example to support your complaint.

Comment: @CodyGray, "*a place where questions are asked and answered*", just like Quora? I go to Electronics and ask how to repair something, or I go to Skeptics and I say I'm skeptical about something and ask whether it's true, and in each case my question gets down voted and closed because it is "off-topic". What do you mean "off-topic"? I asked a question that fits the name of the site. You guys must be crazy. I'm out of here.

Comment: We are pretty crazy. Good luck finding somewhere to go without at least a token amount of craziness. I mean, yeah, there are rules about what the site allows and how it works that are written in [the documentation](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), not plastered at the top of each page. But the simple impression is nevertheless the correct one: this *is* a site for asking & answering questions about programming. There are certain types of questions we don't allow and deem as "off-topic", but that's always going to be so. I never liked making "off-topic" mean "unsuitable", but I got outvoted.

Comment: I can confirm that I indeed am completely insane. :D